# Put requests suddenly not implemented

Tags: attask, workfront-api

It seems as though the Workfront server has stopped accepting PUT requests in the last week or so.  My program was able to set a timesheet's status last week, but this week the request comes back with a 501 error.

Any thoughts?  I tried using several older versions of the program, but they have the same problem which leads me to think it's a server side issue.
I'm simply importing the requests library and calling

```
response = requests.put('https://<subdomain>.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/tshet/<objectId>', params={'status': 'S', 'sessionID': <sessionId>})
```

Thanks,

Z

Comment: I had the same issue. I solved it by changing all of my PUT requests to POST requests then adding `method=put` as one of the parameters. It kinda seems like Workfront changed something without telling anyone.

Comment: Thanks a lot @NickGillum that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue that should be fixed at this point